# Error when running Selenium in a thread in Cloud Run

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver, python-multithreading

I have a Selenium process within my web app that takes some time. So I'd like to run it in the background while the next web page loads. The process uses Chrome to scrape a website and insert data into my database. I have implemented a solution using Threading.

However, when I run the process in Google Cloud Run, I run into the following error.

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable".
```

Strangely, the solution works when deployed in a Docker container locally. The solution also works in Cloud Run when I run the process in sequence (without using threading), so something about the combination of Cloud Run and threading throws the error.

Relevant code snippets below:

From routes.py

```
@app.route("/my_route", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_route():
    search_term = 'search term'
    primary_key = session.get("primary_key")

    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=scrape_function, args=(search_term, primary_key, app))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    return render_template('my_route.html')
```

```
def scrape_function(search_term, primary_key, app):

    with app.app_context():
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

        parsed_url = urllib.parse.quote(search_term)
        driver.get(f'https://google.com?search_query={parsed_url}')

        # seleniuim process to search and click through webpage #

        url = driver.current_url
        driver.quit()

        user = User.query.filter_by(id=primary_key).first()
        user.url = url
        db.session.commit()
        print('Thread Completed')

    return url
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

COPY . /code/
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 -w 3 run:app
```

Comment: For anyone returning here: in Google Cloud Run, it seems by default the CPU is running for your service only when a request is being handled. Since the thread spawns outside of a request, you get weird issues.

What fixed it for me was running the CPU continuously instead of just for requests.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone returning here: in Google Cloud Run, it seems by default the CPU is running for your service only when a request is being handled. Since the thread spawns outside of a request, you get weird issues.

What fixed it for me was running the CPU continuously instead of just for requests. This is a setting under CPU allocation within the Cloud Service.